# Hide inline style background image responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

A project i am working on now lets users upload an image. When an image is uploaded it is added dynamicly to the background image of a div and because of this i used an inline style.

For example:

```
<div style="background:url('<?=$fleet->bg_img?>') right no-repeat;"></div>
```

Now i dont want this bg image to appear on all screen sizes so i want to hide this on all screens below the width of 870px. If the background image was set as a class this would be 
easy to hide on smaller devices using media queries. But because its not im kind of stumped on how i am meant to hide this on smaller devices?

Is there a way for me to hide this background image responsively while still using it as an inline style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a CSS media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 870px) {
    .myDiv {
        background: none !important;
    }
}
```

I do not usually suggest using `!important` but in this instance it would be the only way to override your inline styling.

Comment: Yeah i wasn't sure about using !important but it works perfectly without having to resort to JS. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but for anyone searching for a solution, you could try this instead of `!important`:

```
<div style="background:url('<?=$fleet->bg_img?>') right no-repeat;" class="bg-element"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-element {
      background-size: 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media all and (min-width: 870px){
      .bg-element {
          background-size: cover;
      }
}
```

Using `background-size: 0` makes the background disappear and adding `background-repeat: no-repeat` makes the background color (if one is defined) underneath visible.

And then on the media query you can simply define the size of the background image again and make it visible.

This gives you much more freedom than using `!important` which might always cause problems later if you'd like to override it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add a class like

```
<div style="background:url('<?=$fleet->bg_img?>') right no-repeat;" class="user-bg"></div>
```

and then

```
@media (max-width: 870px){
    .user-bg{
        background-image:none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EgJLK/1/

HTML

```
  <div class="imageClass" style="background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhyWPmOb6wqo1AzCfeS2OIgs_wVY08bXwJrl4fvTwNYSWaM2w0T-O7CJwo');"></div>
```

JQuery/JS

```
  $(function(){
     $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() < 870){
            $('.imageClass').css({'background-image': 'none'});
        }else{
            $('.imageClass').css({'background-image': 'url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhyWPmOb6wqo1AzCfeS2OIgs_wVY08bXwJrl4fvTwNYSWaM2w0T-O7CJwo")'})
        }
     });
   });
```